# How to change column length in table sales_order

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I'm new to Magento. I want to store 3rd party order id and customer id in column **ext_order_id** and **ext_customer_id** in table sales_order.

The problem is these 2 columns have length 32, so I altered the table to set it to 50. However, every time I ran command *bin/magento setup:upgrade*, the column length was reset back to 32, and data in that column was truncated.

Any solution to store 50 characters in those columns?
Thanks

Comment: How have you added two field? directly on table or using script?

Comment: @SweetyMasmiya these 2 columns (ext_order_id and ext_customer_id) are default columns of table sales_order, they are there at beginning, I didn't add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a db_schema.xml in a module of yours and update it there
example here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html